# What functors between categories of algebras are induced by morphisms of monads on $\mathrm{Set}$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

Let $M, N$ be monads of rank $\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a regular cardinal (I'm primarily interested in the case of finitary monads). Is there a known characterization of functors $\mathrm{Alg}~N \to \mathrm{Alg}~M$ (of course, I mean the Eilenberg-Moore category) coming from monad morphisms $M \to N$ (that is, a morphism of monoids in the monoidal category $\mathrm{End}(\mathrm{Set})$)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functor $U_{({-})} : \mathrm{Mnd}(\mathrm{Set})^\circ \to \mathrm{CAT}/\mathrm{Set}$, sending each monad to the forgetful functor from its category of algebras, is fully faithful (Theorem 3 of Frei's [Some remarks on triples](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01110118)). Therefore, a functor between categories of algebras for two monads (regardless of rank) corresponds to a monad morphism if and only if the functor commutes with the forgetful functors.

Given such a functor $F : \mathrm{Alg}(N) \to \mathrm{Alg}(M)$, we define a monad morphism $M \to N$ as follows. For each set $x$, we have a free $N$-algebra $Nx$, which is sent by $F$ to an $M$-algebra on $Nx$. Concretely, such an algebra comprises a function $MN x \to N x$ satisfying two laws. Given this function, we precompose by the unit $M\eta_x : Mx \to MNx$ of $N$, producing a function $Mx \to Nx$. This defines a natural transformation $M \Rightarrow N$, and it can be checked that this is a monad morphism.

In fact, the corresponding statement is true for monads on any category, not just $\mathrm{Set}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Moreover, all such functors automatically have rank $\lambda$ (because their composition with a forgetful functor (which has rank $\lambda$ and is conservative) is a functor of rank $\lambda$) and preserve all limits (for a similar reason), hence are right adjoint functors.

Comment: The fact is that I expected at least such functor properties as right adjoint, rank and wanted to know the full list. But it turned out that everything is so simple. Thanks again!

Comment: I have now found that the same is true for an arbitrary category $C$ ($\mathrm{Set}$ is not essential here). See Francis Borceux - Handbook of categorical algebra II, Prop 4.5.9.

Comment: @ArshakAivazian: yes, I should have mentioned that this doesn't just work for Set (Frei works with monads on an arbitrary base category, for instance). Glad I could help :)